# Vaught's two cardinal theorem using Vaught pairs

Tags: logic, cardinals, model-theory

I've been reading David Marker's Introduction to Model Theory, and found **Vaught's two cardinal theorem** (4.3.34): if a theory $T$ has a $(\kappa,\lambda)$-model, where $\kappa > \lambda \geq \aleph_0$, then $T$ has an $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model.
The proof is made using Vaught pairs, and uses the following: **existence of $(\kappa,\lambda)$-model $\Rightarrow$ existence of Vaught pair $\Rightarrow$ existence of countable Vaught pair $\Rightarrow$ existence of $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model**.
However, when constructing the $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model from a countable Vaught pair it uses the formula that defines the Vaught pair (which may have parameters), and asserts that the same formula can be used to define the $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model (which should not have parameters).
So according to the theorem, a Vaught pair of **Dense linear order without endpoints** should assure the existence of a $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model. I've been able to expose a Vaught pair of **DLO w/o endpoints**.
**QUESTIONS**
**1.** Is there an $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model of the theory?
My guess is not, since seems to me that all elements have the same type over $\emptyset$.
**2.** If the proof of the theorem is wrong, is there an easy workaround? (Not using saturated models, but Vaught pairs)
**3.** If the proof of the theorem is correct, why can you use a formula with parameters to construct the $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that Marker is sloppy on this point. However, if you work through the proofs, you'll see that the formulas witnessing the $(\kappa,\lambda)$ model and the Vaughtian pair and the $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model are all the same. So if you start with a formula without parameters witnessing the $(\kappa,\lambda)$ model, you'll get a Vaughtian pair and an $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model without parameters. On the other hand, if the formula in your Vaughtian pair has parameters, you'll get a formula *with parameters* witnessing the $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model, or, if you prefer, you can add the parameters as constants to the language and get a true $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model.

Comment: You're right. That makes Marker's proof of Morley's categoricity theorem sloppy as well, because it relies on the Baldwin Lachlan characterization of $\kappa$-categorical theories, and states that the existence of a Vaughtian pair implies the existence of a $(\aleph_1,\aleph_0)$-model and hence a $(\kappa,\aleph_0)$-model (with $\omega$-stability). So to make it work, it's necessary to show that $(\kappa,\lambda)$-models with parameters also contradict the $\kappa$-categoricity of the theory (without constants).